# How to calculate percentage increase between rows in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage

I have data like:

```
YEAR_MONTH|AVG_VISITS|WAS_MEMBER
2020-09|10|True
2020-09|5|False
2019-04|2.5|True
2019-04|5|False
```

I'd like to make it into a table that calculates the percentage of visits membership added:

```
YEAR_MONTH|VISIT_PERCENT
2020-09|200
2019-04|50
```

What is the SQL that would let me look between rows for this sort of calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select year_month,
       100 * sum(case when WAS_MEMBER = 'True' then avg_visits end) /
       sum(case when WAS_MEMBER = 'False' then avg_visits end) as perc_increase
  from your_table t
group by year_month
```